# how to sign windows driver for virtual device

Tags: windows, driver, driver-signing

Our company develop a driver for virtual device.
We don't have any hardware.
Do we need to complete the same process as for real hardware?
I have an account in Partner Center for Windows Hardware, do I need to create HLK file to upload this driver ?

Comment: Try asking on the OSR mailing list...

Comment: Do you install your driver with an INF file or just load it?

Comment: Hi @OneAndOnly Same question here. Plan to make it just be loaded because it needs to emulate microphone. Could you please enlighten us how to proceed?